# Internal working of an iterator in python

Tags: python

I have one question when we call an iter(obj)on an iterable(list_1). It returns an iterator object. When we invoke the next method on this iterator object it returns the next value one at a time. My question is does the iterator object(iter_obj) contains the data(after we run the iter method) and it prints out the value one at a time or does it reference/use the iterable(list_1) when running the next(method)

```
list_1=[1,2,3,4]

iter_obj=iter(list_1)

next(iter_obj)
```

Comment: It uses the reference. However, that doesn't mean you're allowed to modify the list while iterating over it.

Comment: The list iterator has the reference to the list and the current index in the list. It does not have its own copy of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second assumption (iterator contains reference to list) is true.

If you have a look into the [C source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bb86bf4c4eaa30b1f5192dab9f389ce0bb61114d/Objects/iterobject.c#L8) of the iter object you'll see that it contains exactly two attributes:

- `it_index`: the index within the sequence `ìt_seq` of the next object that shall be returned by `iter()`
- `it_seq`: the sequence (in your case `list_1`) that shall be iterated